# What was the intended audience of "Absent, Or Not Absent" by Tsering Woeser?

Tags: poetry, chinese-language, tsering-woeser

Tibetan poet and activist Tsering Woeser wrote the poem *Absent, or Not Absent* in Chinese. (The full text is [available from Words Without Borders](https://www.wordswithoutborders.org/article/august-2019-chinese-poetry-absent-or-not-absent-woeser-ian-boyden)). I am somewhat curious as to why she chose to write in Chinese in particular. What was the intended audience and purpose of the poem?